# Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I wish to install WAMP Server on my PC and then Wordpress on Apache.
I successfully installed WAMP. Launched the service to realize that phpmyadmin wasn't working. I was recieving the error mentioned in the title. So i thought of resetting the root password, flushing the privileges and then creating a database(Which i could have done via phpmyadmin).

So i reset the mysql root password. I then tried again to run phpmyadmin..DIDN'T WORK!
(I did edit the config file)

Worst part of it all is that mysql console wont work either! I get the same error!

I am kinda new to all this...Please help1!!! :'(

Answer (score 4):

I changed this:

```
GRANT ALL ON database.* TO user@* IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

to:

```
GRANT ALL ON database.* TO user IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

then it works.

Comment: Can you say where you have changed this?

Answer (score 3):

- Go to cmd.
- cd to `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\bin` (or wtvr path you have)
- run `mysql -uroot -p`
- `GRANT ALL ON database.* TO user@* IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` 
  For example:
  `GRANT ALL ON mydatabase.* TO root@* IDENTIFIED BY 'secretpass';`
- FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Setup config.inc.php from phpMyAdmin correctly (user root, password wtvr, host localhost, etc.):

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'secretpass';
```

Comment: The error was due to multiple instances of Mysql. Uninstalled all of them. And re-installed wamp. Worked!

Comment: One of them should have been up and running, the unninstall fixed some other problems you had.

Comment: mysql -uroot -p this commands gives the same error 'Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server'

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

1) Go to WAMP folder on your C drive.

2) Go to alias folder and open phpmyadmin.conf file

3)
Original file look like this-

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Change it to-

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use this..,

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

mysql> CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: I wish I could have "Ha ha" reaction on Stackoverflow. If I can ot login to mysql then where to execute the query?